# Add text to a specific page of a pdf using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need create a tool that adds a hyperlink every other page for a pdf file.

I followed the iText documentation and I managed to add the hyperlink but only on the first page.

My code:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        Font bold = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 30, Font.BOLD);

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);

        int count = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        Utils.logInfoMessage("Number of pages: " + count, mLogList);
        if(count < 1) {
            Utils.logErrorMessage("file : " + src + " has no pages", mLogList);
            return;
        }

        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

        PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(1);
        PdfGState gState = new PdfGState();
        gState.setFillOpacity(0.1f);
        canvas.setGState(gState);

        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("www.google.com", bold);
        chunk.setAnchor("https://www.google.ro/");

        Phrase phrase = new Phrase("");
        phrase.add(chunk);

        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
        ct.setSimpleColumn(36, 700, 559, 750);
        ct.addText(phrase);
        ct.go();

        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }
```

Any ideas how to add the hyperlink/text only on a specific page?

Comment: Don't know if you resolved this or not but since you already have count there as your number of pages, you just wrap that entire thing in a for loop, for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
  stamper.getOverContent(i <---(here is where you had 1));
}

Comment: PdfStamper does not exist in itext 7. Can you give an updated example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> I followed the iText documentation and I managed to add the hyperlink but only on the first page

This is the iText documentation: [PdfStamper](https://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText5/5.5.13/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html#getOverContent-int-)

> **getOverContent**
>
> `public PdfContentByte getOverContent(int pageNum)`
>
> Gets a `PdfContentByte` to write over the page of the original
>   document.
>
> *Parameters:*
>
> `pageNum` - the page number where the extra content is written
>
> Returns:
>
> a `PdfContentByte` to write over the page of the original document

This is the code you wrote:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(1);
```

You used `1` as the value for `pageNum`.

Now you tell me: if you choose `1` as the page number, then why are you surprised that all the content you add is only added on the first page?

**IMPORTANT:**

You write

> I followed the iText documentation

I assume that you refer to the official documentation on the official iText web page: https://itextpdf.com

If that is correct, then why are you still using an old version of iText? The current version is 7.1.2, and the `PdfStamper` class no longer exists in that version. As explained in [chapter 5](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document) of the [iText 7 Jump-Start tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/) adding content to an existing PDF is done differently nowadays.

FYI: there are some more tutorials here: https://developers.itextpdf.com/books

Comment: Yes, I followed the official iText documentation. So, because i did some copy/paste I didn't realize that the '1' stands for the page number. I just need to create a small tool that will be used once so I just downloaded the first jar that i found. Thanks a lot. It works!

Comment: I am having trouble finding the examples referenced. All the links just take me to https://itextpdf.com/en... which then gives a very convoluted way to download an ebook. Not exactly user friendly  And the ebook is not coming to me though I requested it twice.

Comment: There used to be free coupons somewhere on the website to download the eBook that is available for sale on Leanpub: https://leanpub.com/itext7jump-starttutorial Please note that neither Joris, nor I still work at iText. Our answer dates from 2018 and it's about a version of iText that was already old at the time we provided it. I assume that versions older than iText 5 are no longer supported.